# Lua Corona: unable to center image and have it fill the full screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I tried everything an can't seem to get the image to take up the full screen and be centered. I have attached the image, and how it looks when I run on corona.

I tried this and got what I attached:

```
local background = display.newImageRect( "bg.png", 
display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywHpy.png)

[how it looks on corona](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYFew.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example your `config.lua` is like below

```
application = {
    content = {
        width = 640,
        height = 960, 
        scale = "letterBox",
        fps = 30,
    },
}
```

then use like below to display image in **fullscreen**

```
local background = display.newImageRect( "bg.png", 
640 , 960 )
// then center it like below
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html) you need to pass **width** and **height**, not x and y. Try this:

```
--take screen width and height, so image can take whole screen
local width = display.contentWidth
local height = display.contentHeight
local background = display.newImageRect( "bg.png", width, height)
--setting coordinates to center
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

**Edit**: If you are using `letterbox` scaling mode you should ajust width and height

```
width = display.contentWidth - 2 * display.screenOriginX
height = display.contentHeight - 2 * display.screenOriginY
```

Comment: Depending on scaling method width of screen will not always equal of `display.contentWidth`. For `letterbox`  mode I use `display.contentWidth - 2 * display.screenOriginX` for width. The same apply to height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want preserve aspect ratio of image try

```
local _CX = display.contentCenterX
local _CY = display.contentCenterY
local imgW = 440 -- width of image 
local imgH = 623-- height of image
local imgR = imgH / imgW
local screenW = display.contentWidth - 2 * display.screenOriginX 
local screenH = display.contentHeight - 2 * display.screenOriginY 
local screenR = screenH / screenW
local factor = imgR > screenR and screenW / imgW or screenH / imgH

local background = display.newImageRect( 'bg.jpg', imgW * factor, imgH * factor )
background .x, background .y = _CX, _CY
```

I tested code against `letterbox` mode.

Other solution from Corona forum [How to make an image full screen?](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/70242-how-to-make-an-image-full-screen/#entry366566):

> if you want to fill the screen with an image, it's better to make the
>   image larger than any potential screen aspect ratio, then accept some
>   amount of clipping on certain screens when the image goes beyond the
>   edges.